# js/jquery - Textarea value is a email html template, how to validate with a tag/attribute whitelist, without removing the invalid tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, email-templates

As described in subject, I need to prevent submission of email templates that contain unexpected tags/attribute/attribute values and also provide a feedback on what triggered the validation fail, without directly modifying the content user tried to submit. That is the main problem because I only found html sanitizing apps, while I want to preserve user input

I already did the validations at server with anglesharp, but I was wondering if I can use an existing library, instead of bruteforcing it with regex expressions.

The website is a simple simple MVC app, with boostrap and jquery